# handleKeyPress method is called multiple times in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let [a, setA] = useState(0);
  let [b, setB] = useState(0);

  document.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyPress);

  function handleKeyPress() {
    console.log("event occured!");
    setA(a + 1);
    setB(b + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{a}</h1>
      <h2>{b}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am setting the two states at a time in react. i read  https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html and  [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). still not find what is wrong with my code. I have been trying to fix this issue for the past 24 hours using Google and asking friends for help. none of them worked. if you have any idea please guide me. thanks!

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-rhodes-icwyx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Why you are using Key up on document? What exactly you have to do?

Comment: for taking input from the user. i tried keyup and keydown.but the issue occurs on all of them @AkhilThakur

Comment: Can you share the link instead of the image?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-rhodes-icwyx?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an event listener once on the component's mount.

Currently, you add a listener **on every** render.

```
export default function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(0);
  const [b, setB] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleKeyPress() {
      console.log('event occured!');
      setA(p => p + 1);
      setB(b => b + 1);
    }

    document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyPress);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{a}</h1>
      <h2>{b}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit dreamy-hugle-xqm37]

Comment: hi thanks! the code works! but what i have done wrong with my code. can you guide me with any documentation or videos where i can learn what i have done wrong with my code. thanks. @Dennish Vash

Comment: Read about lifecycles and hooks. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html This will help you to understand hooks.